# Differentiating between a record that exists and one that is new in ef partial class

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework

Thanks to the good offices of people here I came to realise that if one has a constructor in a partial class in ones entity model it will be called whenever records are retrieved or when actual new records are created.

I have been searching for a simple example of how one might differentiate between the two so that property assignments added to the constructor are only ever applied to ne records.  If anyone knows of such a sample or could provide one here (preferably in VB.net) I would be most grateful.

Here is a typical example of the sort of thing I'd like to only get called when a new record was being created as opposed to whenever a record was retrieved.

```
Public Sub New()
    OrderNumber = te.UpdateAndReturnSalesOrderNumber.FirstOrDefault
    OrderDate = Now
    Posted = False

End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while since I've played with the partial classes and thus don't remember the order of things.

But, if you have an ID you could check for the default value (i.e., 0 or empty) after EF hydrates your class.

I think I remember doing something like this.

Comment: Thank you Tony, I shall look into that.